# Python: remove NaN- named columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns named *nan* that are not strings. How could I remove these?

I tried with

```
df.drop(np.nan, axis=1)
```

which did not work.

I found a dirty way around by renaming nans as below:

```
df.columns= df.columns.fillna('type')
df.drop('type', axis=1)
```

However I don't think that this is the most efficient way. Is there a better way to remove columns that are named nans?

Comment: [`df.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)

Comment: Are the columns named "nan", or are values in them NaNs? If the former, use `df.drop(["nan"])` instead, but it seems unlikely you'd have two columns both named "nan".

Answer (score 2):

For me your solution working:

```
df = df.drop(np.nan, axis=1)
```

Another solution is remove by boolean mask:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':list('abcdef'),
                   'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
                   np.nan:[7,8,9,4,2,3],
                   'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
                   'F':list('aaabbb')})

df = df.loc[:, pd.notnull(df.columns)]
print (df)
   A  B  D  E  F
0  a  4  1  5  a
1  b  5  3  3  a
2  c  4  5  6  a
3  d  5  7  9  b
4  e  5  1  2  b
5  f  4  0  4  b
```

**Detail**:

```
print (pd.notnull(df.columns))
[ True  True False  True  True  True]
```